# Проблемы с таймингами в loop nexcord

Tags: python, discord

````
@tasks.loop(hours = 6.0)
async def welcome_seend():
  now = datetime.now().hour
  if now in [00, 6, 12, 18, 14]:
      channel = await bot.fetch_channel(967746240601292813)
      await channel.send('```diff\n-Уважаемые сотрудники копропрации  контрольные  захват начнеться чрез два часа, будьте осторожнее при перемещении по зоне\n```')
````

В теории бот каждые 6 часов присылает сообщение, но он опаздывает на 50+ минут, как решить такую проблему?

Comment: В теории вообще чудо, что ваши сообщения отправляются. Какая вероятность того, что программа запускаемая каждые 6 часов, попадет именно в эти числа? Особенно в 14 часов?

Comment: @СергейКох Я понял свои ошибки, начал вызывать таск раз в минуту, понял, что now выдает str а нужно перевести во float. 
Но все равно есть задержка в 50 секунд :(

Comment: @Karasmhi `начал вызывать таск раз в минуту` `задержка в 50 секунд` Ну вызывайте чаще на столько, на сколько нужна точность.